# Java Set Window's "Document"

Tags: java, swing, document, title

In certain Mac applications, when a document is open, the title of the window will become the document name and the window will have the icon. Right clicking on the title shows you the path to the file. I was wondering if there was a way in to do this in Java.

[image]

Comment: Not with out going through some kind of JNI/JNA solution AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to achieve this by setting the `"Window.documentFile"` client property of your JFrame's rootPane.  From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#WINDOW_DOCUMENTFILE :

> **Window.documentFile**
>
> Type: java.io.File
>
> Applies to: JRootPane
>
> This property adds a document proxy icon to the title bar of the window. This icon is the effective representation of the document that can be dragged and dropped into the Finder or the Dock. Command-clicking on the title will present the full path to the document in a popup. The proxy icon in the title bar will have the icon of document as presented by LaunchServices in the Finder or Open and Save dialog boxes. This property can be changed at anytime throughout the lifetime of the window.

Example code:

```
public void open(File file) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My App");
    frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.documentFile", file);
    frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.documentModified", false);

    // Load file
}
```

Comment: This is correct in both Apple's JDK 6 and in Oracle's JDK 7 and beyond.